# Segments start address is different in IDApython when invoked thrg cmd prompt

Tags: idapython, dll, command-line

I am able to get Segments start address, end address and all functions of a DLL through follwoing ida python script:

```
# Get the segment's starting address
    ea = ScreenEA()
    print(ea)
    print(SegStart(ea),SegEnd(ea))

    callers = dict()
    callees = dict()

    # Loop through all the functions

    for function_ea in Functions(SegStart(ea), SegEnd(ea)):

        f_name = GetFunctionName(function_ea)
        print(f_name)

        # Create a set with all the names of the functions calling (referring to)
        # the current one.
        callers[f_name] = Set(map(GetFunctionName, CodeRefsTo(function_ea, 0)))

        # For each of the incoming references
        for ref_ea in CodeRefsTo(function_ea, 0):


            # Get the name of the referring function
            caller_name = GetFunctionName(ref_ea)

            # Add the current function to the list of functions
            # called by the referring function
            callees[caller_name] = callees.get(caller_name, Set())
            callees[caller_name].add(f_name)

    # Get the list of all functions
    functions = Set(callees.keys()+callers.keys())
    total_callees=0

    # For each of the functions, print the number of functions calling it and
    # number of functions being called. In short, indegree and outdegree
    for f in functions:
        print('%d:%s:%d' % (len(callers.get(f, [])), f, len(callees.get(f, []))))
        total_callees+=len(callees.get(f,[]))

    print("\nTotal callees of \t"+idaapi.get_root_filename()+"\t: "+str(total_callees))
```

Script is working well when invoked inside IDA pro but if it is invoked through command prompt like below:

```
idaq.exe -A -S"C:\xxx\segment.py" "C:\fff\yy.dll"
```

The output is different as below:

```
4294967295
(4294967295L, 4294967295L)    
Total callees of    yy.dll  : 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are starting from the `ScreenEA()` return value - this function returns the current EA in the disassembly window. When you're running from the command line it really can behave different.

To iterate over segments you can use `idautils.Segments()` function (it allows iteration over all defined segments). If you want to get the first defined segment you can use `idc.FirstSeg()` which should return the start address of the first segment. If you want to limit the work of your script to one segment you can check segment name with function `idc.SegName(ea)`, where ea is an address within the segment, for example, as follows:

```
import idautils
import idc

for s in idautils.Segments():
    if idc.SegName(s) == "your_segment_name":
         #do you work here
```

By the way, `4294967295` in hex is `0xffffffff` which is numeric value of `idc.BADADDR`, which means invalid address or error.

Comment: Thanks! but unable to pass arguments to script...idaq64  -A -S"myscrip.py outpath.txt" "bin_path" gives idc.argv[0] argument error while running the script

Comment: did you use it as `idc.argv` or as `idc.ARGV` ?

Comment: idc.ARGV and its working :) last doubt ! how to find hanging instructions i.e those intructions which are not under any function module in a DLL using IDAPython?

Comment: I'd suggest to ask it as different question.